# magit for `pull --rebase upstream` (not origin)

Tags: emacs, magit

Let's say we have an `upstream` git repository which is the official home of a project, and `origin` is our own remote git repository (e.g. a github fork).

On the command line, I would rebase to the master before issuing a PR with

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

but how do I do this in magit? The `F` command allows a `--rebase` but that's always against my `origin` as far as I can tell.

Ideally, I'd like to do this with a single command under the `F` menu as it is a very common operation for me.

Comment: On the next branch (to be 2.1.0), the rebase menu has an 'o' action to select another branch.  So this would be 'F-ro'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `magit`, you can use the `C-u` prefix argument to allow you to set the remote for push and pull operations. You would type `C-u F -r F upstream<RET>` to do this. If you need to also specify the branch name, you can double the `C-u` prefix: `C-u C-u F -r F upstream<RET> master<RET>`. In the next version of Magit, 2.1.0, this will be available in the more accessible `F -r o` rather than having to use the prefix argument.

If that's too cumbersome, I suggest setting the upstream explicitly in your `.git/config`; then all pulls will come from that upstream. You can do this with `git branch -u upstream/master` while on your local branch, or `git branch -u upstream/master mybranch` if you're on a different branch. Then, whether you use Magit or `git` on the command line, a simple `git pull --rebase` or `F -r F` will pull from the configured branch.

If you need to push to your own personal repo while pulling from a different repo, you can always set up a separate remotes for pushes and pulls. There is no convenient command wrapper for this that I know of, but if you edit your `.git/config` directly, you would do so as follows:

```
[branch "mybranch"]
remote = upstream
pushremote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

If you're doing this, and will always be rebasing your local branch, you could even add:

```
rebase = true
```

And not have to specify `--rebase` ever time you pull.

If you want to do this for your whole repo, instead of a single branch, you can use:

```
[remote]
pushdefault = origin
```

And then have the branches pull from their configured upstream, but push to your own repo.

Comment: `C-u F` and `F C-u` don't seem to be recognised (also, this is getting dangerously close to rude if there was a `k` flag! :-P)

Comment: What version of magit are you using? Also, did you see my edit in which I listed the full command? The `C-u` comes before the first `F`, in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: oh, that did ask for the ref, even though it seemed to be silently ignored until the end. But 1) this didn't work because my upstream branch has a different name 2) This is ridiculously complex... I'd like a single command for this that appears in the list. Is that possible?

Comment: @fommil To specify a branch as well, you press `C-u` twice. `C-u C-u F -r F upstream<RET> master<RET>`. It will allow you to autocomplete on the remote and branch names, so you don't have to type the entire thing. There isn't another way to do it from within Magit. `C-u` is an Emacs convention for this kind of thing; it's the "Universal argument" that many commands use to distinguish between different variants; in Magit, for the push and pull commands, adding it once allows you to change the remote and twice the remote and branch.

Comment: @fommil However, what you could do to make it more convenient is set your upstream branch for this branch, to be `upstream/master`; you can do that with `git branch -u upstream/master` while on your local branch (or `git branch -u upstream/master mybranch` if you're not currently on it). You can see the change that makes in your `.git/config`, where you will now be configured to push and pull from that particular upstream, so you won't need to specify it ever time.

Comment: setting my upstream branch to be upstream/master would be an absolute disaster. An accidental push would nuke my team's repo and we'd have to get into version rewriting. I think I'll stick with the CLI for this... I'm afraid `magit` just falls short on a few things. Is there no way to script this?

Comment: @fommil Of course you can script it; everything is written in elisp, you could add your own menu entry for doing what you want. I'm just answering your question by showing how you currently do it in magit. Anyhow, updated my answer further to describe how you can set different branches for pushing and pulling in your `.git/config`, which I think should do what you need.

Comment: thanks! The separate remote and pushremote is new to me and probably solves the problem... I hope it works for my whole repo and not just one branch.

Comment: @fommil Updated again with how to make it the default for your whole repo, instead of the single branch

Comment: omg, this is amazing. I came here asking a question about magit and it turns out I've been doing git wrong for all these years! This one little line has just completely simplified my workflow

Comment: this doesn't seem to work from magit. Your suggestion works fine from the command line (which is still a great improvement to my workflow!), but magit push (at least in dry run) is ignoring both branch-level `pushdefault` and any remote.pushdefault in my global config.

Answer (score 1):

If you open `magit-pull-popup`, there's a variable/option to toggle rebase.